# TYPO3 write name of sys_category into class name at tx_news

Tags: typo3, categories, fluid, typo3-8.x, tx-news

I'using `TYPO3 8.7` and write the name of a `sys_category`into the class name of `tx_news`-template Item.html, like this:

```
<div class="{f:format.case(value: '{newsItem.firstCategory.title}', mode: 'lower')}"> ...
```

Now one of my categories has two words, like 'my category', so the classname results:

```
<div class="my category">
```

How can I remove the empty ' ' from class name in `FLUID`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also i would think about using the category uid instead of category name. As names are brittle. An editor might rename somthing and your css code breaks. But your pretty save if you use uids

Comment: Hi, now I use 'cat-1, cat-2, cat-3, ..' and so on .. it's more flexible. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by default - However I see the following options:

1) Create a custom ViewHelper: This would be the best solution as you don't need any 3rd party extension as dependency.

2) Misuse a different field of the category record like `seo_title`, `description` or similiar

3) You could use the replace VH of EXT:vhs, see https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Format/ReplaceViewHelper.html

Comment: Hey Georg, thanks for your quick answer. Mmmhh... or 4) use another category name .. ;)   ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your css to recognize double classes as well.

.category
.my.category

Still the way to go should be unique identifiers instead of names or titles.

Comment: Good idea! I need the 'classname' for my `data-type="my category"` but only for CSS it will be ok. Thanks Jo.